# Evaluar campos de un array con dos valores

Tags: javascript, array, condiciones, bucles

estoy desarollando una grafica donde **tengo que evaluar las emisiones mes a mes**, si ese mes no tiene ponerle un cero y asi crear un array con 12 valores (uno por mes) donde me ponga 0 o el valor que corresponda. Para ello he hecho esto:

```
  const array = []
  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    let existsDatoMes = false;
    for (let j = 0; j < mesesGenerado.length; j++) {
      if (mesesGenerado[j].month === i) {
        existsDatoMes = true
      }
    }
 
   if (existsDatoMes==true) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mesesGenerado.length; j++) {
       array.push(mesesGenerado[j].co2)
      } 
   }else {
        array.push(0)
   }
  }
  console.log(array)
```

el `mesesGenerado` es el array que me devuelve las emisiones, en este caso un array de 4, solo 4 meses tienen emisiones.

El error es que en vez devolverme un array de 12 **me devuelve un array de 24 duplicando los valores**,

```
"Array(24) [ 0, 0, 0, 161.28, 61.44, 453674.8, 1008765.75, 161.28, 61.44, 453674.8, … ]"
```

​

como podria arreglarlo? gracias!!

Comment: porque usas otro for para  hacer la insercion al arreglo `array.push(mesesGenerado[j].co2)` pudiendo hacerlo en el segundo for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez algo asi te sirva:

```
// Para guardar resultados
const array = [];

// Assumo los datos vienen algo asi: Enero es month:0, Febrero es month:1, etc...
const mesesGenerado = [
  {
    month: 3,
    co2: 161.28,
  },
  {
    month: 5,
    co2: 61.44,
  },
  {
    month: 6,
    co2: 453674.8,
  },
  {
    month: 7,
    co2: 1008765.75,
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  const co2 = mesesGenerado.filter((mes) => mes.month === i)?.[0]?.co2 || 0;
  array.push(co2);
}

console.log(array); // [ 0, 0, 0, 161.28, 0, 61.44, 453674.8, 1008765.75, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes simplificar un poco utilizando array map y find. Seria algo como:

```js
const mesesGenerado = [
  {
    month: 1,
    co2: 111,
  },
  {
    month: 4,
    co2: 222,
  },
  {
    month: 8,
    co2: 333,
  },
  {
    month: 12,
    co2: 444,
  },
];

const mesesCo2 = [...Array(12).keys()].map(
  (mes) => mesesGenerado.find(
    (mesGenerado) => mesGenerado.month === mes,
  )?.co2 || 0,
);

console.log(mesesCo2);
```